# Definition of Nil List in Scala

Tags: scala

I do not quite understand the definition of Nil List in a Scala textbook. The  List is defined as follows:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
  case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
  case class Cons[+A] (head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

1. Why Nil is not a class ?
2. Why Nil does not extend List[A] ?
3. Can I define the Nil case as:

   case class Nil extends List[A] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Since `Nil` doesn't take any arguments, it can be a singleton object, so no overhead on creating it each time you create a new `List`.
2. `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type. Extending from `List[Nothing]` makes possible to use `Nil` with any `List[A]`.
3. No, because `object` cannot be parameterized.

Comment: `Nothing` is a sub-*type* of every other type, but it is not a sub-*class* of every other class. In Scala, classes can have at most 1 superclass, so that would not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Nil` is not a class because it doesn't take any parameters. When a class does not take any arguments and doesn't have mutable state, it can just as well be an object.
2. Because what would `A` be? If you do make `Nil` a class, you could make it take `A` as a type parameter, but then you'd have to supply that type parameter in various cases where it can't be inferred.
3. No, that's not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents, let's say you want to define your own implementations of lists as follows:

```
trait List[A]
case class Nil[A]() extends List[A]
case class Cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

This is completely valid `Scala`.

But you might realize, why do I need `Nil()` to be a case class? I want it to be the bottom element for all types of lists, so `Nil[Int]()` should be the same empty list as `Nil[String]()`.

```
scala> Nil[Int]()
res3: Nil[Int] = Nil()

scala> Cons(1,Nil[Int]())
res4: Cons[Int] = Cons(1,Nil())

scala> Cons("a",Nil[Int]())
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Nil[Int]
 required: List[Any]
Note: Int <: Any, but trait List is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
              Cons("a",Nil[Int]())
                           ^
```

Therefore, for all kinds of lists, there exists only one empty list, and we may want to see it as a solely instance (a singleton object).

As `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type, we might think that `Nil` is of type `List[Nothing]`. Hence, we end up with this implementation:

```
trait List[A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

So far, so good. But wait...

```
scala> Cons(1, Nil)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Nil.type
 required: List[Int]
Note: Nothing <: Int (and Nil.type <: List[Nothing]), but trait List is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
              Cons(1, Nil)
                      ^
```

*trait List is invariant in type A*... what the heck? This is where covariance enters to the game. What covariance states is that, for our trait `List`, if `A` is a subtype of `B` then `List[A]` is a subtype of `List[B]`.

Let's go back to our example, we've got that `Nothing` is a subtype for any `A`, so we should require that `List[Nothing]` is also a subtype of any `List[A]`, thus we need to make our type `A` covariant, like so:

```
trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A] (head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

scala> Cons(1, Nil)
res0: Cons[Int] = Cons(1,Nil)
```